# I can't seem to get the last inserted record/id from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, dbo

I got a question. I can't seem to get the last inserted record/id from my MySQL database/table. I want to return the last inserted id from the column 'tag_id', but I'm not getting anything back at all. I'm using DBO by the way. I tried both the 'mysql_insert_id' and the 'lastInsertId', but no success.

My database table looks like this:

Table name: gitags_tags

```
  tag_id  |  name  
----------+---------
   437    |  2011
   438    |  2012
   439    |  2013
   440    |  new
```

My PHP looks like this (in this case I want to return '440'):

```
/*
* Insert the new tagname in the database in the table 'gitags_tags'
*/
$query = "INSERT INTO gitags_tags (`name`) VALUES ('".$new_tagname."')";
$db->setQuery($query);

if (!$db->query()) {
    echo "Something went wrong \n";
    echo $query . "\n";
    exit;
}

// Neither of these two work ...
echo mysql_insert_id();
echo $db->lastInsertId('tag_id');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It must be a Joomla issue. Please [*read this*](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3600870.htm).

Comment: If you're trying to get data from the database, please show you `select` query, not your `insert` query. Read the Joomla documentation on coding database queries using Joomla standards! http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase ....and.... http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: try this  var_dump($db->mysql_insert_id());

Comment: The var_dump gives 'NULL'.

Comment: Do you really want the last tag or do you want the one you were handling i.e. to get the key? THe problem with most of these approaches for the latter is that some other process could have inserted after yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last inserted record, you could use this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('tag_id'))
 ->from($db->quoteName('gitags_tags'))
 ->order($db->quoteName('tag_id') . ' DESC');

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using an invalid Joomla DB function, use `echo $db->insertid();` instead.

Comment: This finally is what worked for me. So frustrating ha.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by echoing a new SQL query with DESC and LIMIT. Like this:

```
SELECT tag_id FROM gitags_tags ORDER BY tag_id  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure the tag_id has set as primary key and increment as well.

```
/*
* Insert the new tagname in the database in the table 'gitags_tags'
*/
$query = "INSERT INTO gitags_tags (`name`) VALUES ('".$new_tagname."')";
$db->setQuery($query);

echo mysql_insert_id();
echo $db->lastInsertId('tag_id');

//Use select query and echo this record with this tag_id.
```